# Symfony 3 Developer page is not showing properly

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, xampp, symfony

i'm currently learing to handle symfony 3 and following along [this](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony/twig-layouts) tutorial

but i have some errors with the right showing of the page, when i coded something wrong in symphony.

this is how it looks now:
[image: Symfony error page]

pretty bad...
but it should look like this:
[image]

what am i missing? is there something wrong with the path?

here is something from the log file:

```
Stack Trace

    in vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Parser.php at line 400  +
    at Twig_Parser ->filterBodyNodes (object(Twig_Node_Text))
    in vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Parser.php at line 413  +
    at Twig_Parser ->filterBodyNodes (object(Twig_Node))
    in vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Parser.php at line 113  +
    at Twig_Parser ->parse (object(Twig_TokenStream))
    in var\cache\dev\classes.php at line 3807  +
    at Twig_Environment ->parse (object(Twig_TokenStream))
    in var\cache\dev\classes.php at line 3835  +
    at Twig_Environment ->compileSource (object(Twig_Source))
    in var\cache\dev\classes.php at line 3686  +
    at Twig_Environment ->loadTemplate ('genus/show.html.twig')
    in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine.php at line 126  +
    at TwigEngine ->load ('genus/show.html.twig')
    in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine.php at line 50  +
    at TwigEngine ->render ('genus/show.html.twig', array('name' => 'octopus', 'notes' => array('Hello dude it is amazing to use twig', 'as a html css template', 'as a html css template')))
    in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine.php at line 50  +
    at TwigEngine ->render ('genus/show.html.twig', array('name' => 'octopus', 'notes' => array('Hello dude it is amazing to use twig', 'as a html css template', 'as a html css template')))
    in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine.php at line 75  +
    at TwigEngine ->renderResponse ('genus/show.html.twig', array('name' => 'octopus', 'notes' => array('Hello dude it is amazing to use twig', 'as a html css template', 'as a html css template')), null)
    in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php at line 212  +
    at Controller ->render ('genus/show.html.twig', array('name' => 'octopus', 'notes' => array('Hello dude it is amazing to use twig', 'as a html css template', 'as a html css template')))
    in src\AppBundle\Controller\GenusController.php at line 31  +
    at GenusController ->showAction ('octopus')
    at call_user_func_array (array(object(GenusController), 'showAction'), array('octopus'))
    in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php at line 153  +
    at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
    in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php at line 68  +
    at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
    in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php at line 169  +
    at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
    in web\app_dev.php at line 28  +
    at require ('C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\web\app_dev.php')
    in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Resources\config\router_dev.php at line 40  +

Logs  -
1 error

    INFO - Matched route "{route}".
    INFO - Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "A template that extends another one cannot include contents outside Twig blocks. Did you forget to put the contents inside a {% block %} tag in "genus/show.html.twig" at line 2?" at C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Parser.php line 400
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".
    DEBUG - Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}".

Stack Trace (Plain Text)  -

[1] Twig_Error_Syntax: A template that extends another one cannot include contents outside Twig blocks. Did you forget to put the contents inside a {% block %} tag in "genus/show.html.twig" at line 2?
    at n/a
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Parser.php line 400

    at Twig_Parser->filterBodyNodes(object(Twig_Node_Text))
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Parser.php line 413

    at Twig_Parser->filterBodyNodes(object(Twig_Node))
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Parser.php line 113

    at Twig_Parser->parse(object(Twig_TokenStream))
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 3807

    at Twig_Environment->parse(object(Twig_TokenStream))
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 3835

    at Twig_Environment->compileSource(object(Twig_Source))
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 3686

    at Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('genus/show.html.twig')
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine.php line 126

    at Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine->load('genus/show.html.twig')
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine.php line 50

    at Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine->render('genus/show.html.twig', array('name' => 'octopus', 'notes' => array('Hello dude it is amazing to use twig', 'as a html css template', 'as a html css template')))
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine.php line 50

    at Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->render('genus/show.html.twig', array('name' => 'octopus', 'notes' => array('Hello dude it is amazing to use twig', 'as a html css template', 'as a html css template')))
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine.php line 75

    at Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->renderResponse('genus/show.html.twig', array('name' => 'octopus', 'notes' => array('Hello dude it is amazing to use twig', 'as a html css template', 'as a html css template')), null)
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 212

    at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->render('genus/show.html.twig', array('name' => 'octopus', 'notes' => array('Hello dude it is amazing to use twig', 'as a html css template', 'as a html css template')))
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\src\AppBundle\Controller\GenusController.php line 31

    at AppBundle\Controller\GenusController->showAction('octopus')
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(GenusController), 'showAction'), array('octopus'))
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php line 153

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php line 68

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php line 169

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\web\app_dev.php line 28

    at require('C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\web\app_dev.php')
        in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphony\enc_file_service\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Resources\config\router_dev.php line 40
```

**EDIT:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Genus {{ name }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h2 class="genus-name">{{ name }}</h2>
    <div class="sea-creature-container">
        <div class="genus-photo"></div>
        <div class="genus-details">
            <dl class="genus-details-list">
                <dt>Subfamily:</dt>
                <dd>Octopodinae</dd>
                <dt>Known Species:</dt>
                <dd>289</dd>
                <dt>Fun Fact:</dt>
                <dd>{{ funFact|raw }}</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="js-notes-wrapper"></div>
    <section id="cd-timeline">
    </section>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel" src="{{ asset('js/notes.react.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
        var notesUrl = '{{ path('genus_show_notes', {'genusName': name}) }}';

        ReactDOM.render(
                <NoteSection url={notesUrl} />,
                document.getElementById('js-notes-wrapper')
        );
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you please share code of your `show.html.twig` file. It seems you forgot to add  `{% block %}` statement.

Comment: @Sameer done now live

Comment: but i dont have a question about the issue. the issue is there because i did so... to see what the error page does. but then my error page from symfony is showing not properly. what is there?

Comment: Maybe this could be a cache problem? Have you tried `$ php bin/console cache:clear` in your terminal, and refresh after that?

Comment: Nope didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the error:

```
[1] Twig_Error_Syntax: A template that extends another one cannot include contents outside Twig blocks. Did you forget to put the contents inside a {% block %} tag in "genus/show.html.twig" at line 2?
```

It's like you have a empty tag in genus/show.html.twig line 2, set which block

Comment: This is an error jeah but the error page from symfony is not loading properly